# Simple MySQL Issue

Tags: mysql

OK I have a column with a `W` or `L` to designate a win or loss. I want to count all the wins and losses, and get a win percentage.

```
SELECT banner_name, count(win_loss) as wins 
FROM drop_log 
where win_loss = 'W' 
group by banner_name
```

This gives me all the teams and how many wins they have. How would I tweak this to have another column for losses and another one for ratio. MySQL appears to have different syntax rules than SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would recommend that you use a integer instead of a string to designate a win or a lost.  It's a lot faster and more efficient.  Also what language are you using to interface with MySQL?

Comment: You're wrong that your query gives you _how many wins they have_. It gives you how many games they played -- `count(win_loss)` counts both wins and losses.

Comment: The db was made by another guy; I am just helping. Kind of the blind leading the blind here lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT banner_name, SUM(IF(win_loss = "W", 1, 0)) AS wins,
    SUM(IF(win_loss = "L", 1, 0)) AS losses
FROM drop_log
GROUP BY banner_name
```

You may also be able to get the percentage in this way, but it's easy to divide after the selection too.

It would also be better to use a boolean (`0` or `1`) to designate a win or loss, but this would work in pretty much the same way.

EDIT: It would actually work to simply use `SUM(win_loss = 'letter')` as this will return `1` or `0` already.

Comment: Wow quick response : ) Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BillKarwin Why? They're both allowed. Is that an ANSI thing?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, in ANSI SQL, double-quotes are used to delimit identifiers, like how MySQL uses back-ticks.  If you `SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES`, it makes MySQL conform to the standard, but then anyone who has been in the habit of using double-quotes for string or date literals will find their queries break.  So just get into the habit of using single-quotes for strings and dates, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all 3 values you want.

```
SELECT banner_name, wins, total-wins AS losses, wins/total AS win_ratio
FROM (select banner_name, SUM(win_losses = 'W') AS wins, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM drop_log
      GROUP BY banner_name) w
```